# Инициализация IFilter из IStream

Tags: c++, windows, com

Индексирую в своем приложении офисные документы (MS Office 03, 07). Если загружать `IFilter` с использованием конкретного файла, все ок, фильтр работает как надо:

```
HRESULT hr_f = LoadIFilter(filename, 0, (void **)&pFilter);
```

Однако инициализация из буфера:

```
HRESULT hr_ss = BindIFilterFromStream(spStream, 0, (void **)&pFilter);
```

возвращает `E_FAIL`, и `pFilter`, естественно, не работает.
От `IStream` унаследовался, методы реализовал, основное, что нужно для инициализации нужного плагина, подозреваю, творится в в методе:

```
HRESULT StreamFilter::Stat(STATSTG * pstatstg, DWORD grfStatFlag)
{
   //Microsoft Office Ifilter from Windows Registry
   const IID CLSID_IFilter = {
       0xf07f3920,
       0x7b8c,
       0x11cf,
       { 0x9b, 0xe8, 0x00, 0xaa, 0x00, 0x4b, 0x99, 0x86 }

       //{f07f3920-7b8c-11cf-9be8-00aa004b9986}
   };
   LARGE_INTEGER pSize;
   int fl = GetFileSizeEx(_hFile, &pSize);
   memset(pstatstg, 0, sizeof(STATSTG));
   pstatstg->clsid = CLSID_IFilter;
   pstatstg->type = STGTY_STREAM;
   pstatstg->cbSize.QuadPart = pSize.QuadPart;

   return S_OK;
}
```

Варианты инициализации структуры `pstatstg` пробовал разные, все бесполезно...
После вызова этого метода, судя по стеку вызовов уходит в query.dll и оттуда уже мне приходит `E_FAIL`. Ума не приложу, что еще может быть нужно.

Есть похожий вопрос, [Using IFilter in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313828/using-ifilter-in-c-sharp-and-retrieving-file-from-database-rather-than-file-syst/19504946?s=1%7C0.1214#19504946), и метод описанный для *.pdf действительно работает в плюсах. Но к несчастью для MSO не подходит.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, после долгих поисков, я, вдохновившись решением в [этом кейсе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313828/using-ifilter-in-c-sharp-and-retrieving-file-from-database-rather-than-file-syst/19504946?s=1%7C0.1214#19504946), напилил свои костыли, которые работают так, как мне требуется.

Даем возможность системе выбрать нужный хэндлер по расширению обрабатываемого файла:

```
HRESULT hr = LoadIFilter(L".doc", 0, (void **)&pFilter);
```

Затем нужно проинициализировать наш `IStream*`:

```
IPersistStream *stream;
HRESULT hr_qi = pFilter->QueryInterface(&stream);

std::ifstream ifs(filename, ios::binary);
std::string content((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)),
    (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

IStream *comStream;
HGLOBAL hMem = ::GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, content.size());
LPVOID pDoc = ::GlobalLock(hMem);
memcpy(pDoc, content.c_str(), content.size());
::GlobalUnlock(hMem);
HRESULT hr_mem = ::CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hMem, true, &comStream);
HRESULT hr_stream_load = stream->Load(comStream);
```

А далее работаем с фильтром, как в примерах из MSDN или GitHub:

```
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
  DWORD flags = 0;
  HRESULT hr = pFilter->Init(IFILTER_INIT_INDEXING_ONLY |
                             IFILTER_INIT_APPLY_INDEX_ATTRIBUTES |
                             IFILTER_INIT_APPLY_CRAWL_ATTRIBUTES |
                             IFILTER_INIT_FILTER_OWNED_VALUE_OK |
                             IFILTER_INIT_APPLY_OTHER_ATTRIBUTES,
                             0, 0, &flags);
  if (FAILED(hr))
  {
     pFilter->Release();
     throw exception("IFilter::Init() failed");
  }

  Start();

  STAT_CHUNK stat;
  while (SUCCEEDED(hr = pFilter->GetChunk(&stat)))
  {
     if ((stat.flags & CHUNK_TEXT) != 0)
        ProcessTextChunk(pFilter, stat);

     if ((stat.flags & CHUNK_VALUE) != 0)
        ProcessValueChunk(pFilter, stat);
  }

  Finish();

  pFilter->Release();      
}
else
{
  throw exception("LoadIFilter() failed");
}
```

Следует подчеркнуть, что в этой ситуации НЕТ необходимости имплементить свою версию `IStream*`, только если вы не пишите плагин обработки собственного формата для Windows Search.